# Why do we use Δ to mean heating?

Tags: heat, temperature, notation, reaction-control

To express heating, we usually use $\Delta$ over reaction arrows like
\begin{align}
\ce{CaCO3 ->[\Delta] CaO +CO2}.
\end{align}
Why do we use $\Delta$ to mean heating during chemical reactions? I thought up with one idea that $\Delta$ symbolizes fire. But actually I have no information about the origin of this usage. Does anybody know the origin or reason of this usage of $\Delta$?

Comment: Good question, I would like to know how widespread the triangle is as symbol for heating

Comment: It looks like a Bunsen burner flame. It used to be below the arrow.

Comment: adding heat does not mean an increase in temperature it means to define a temperature and run the reaction at that temperature. Reactions are usually run at constant T and P.

Comment: @user55119- Just as $\ce{CaCO_3}$-> $\ce{Ca(HCO_3)}_2$-$\ce{H_2CO_3}$ or $\ce{Ca(HCO_3)}_2$-$\ce{H_2O}$-$\ce{CO_2}$

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/105105/why-do-we-use-%ce%94-to-mean-heating

Comment: @Karsten♦- I want you to put a space between "or" and the symbol of Calcium Bicarbonate in  the second half of the equation where you do break carbonic acid into water and carbon dioxide, no need to give it in the first half of the equation where you do not break carbonic acid into water and carbon dioxide, in one comment which I gave as a reply to @user55119 yesterday, on doing the needful in that one, you will be able to delete this recent comment which I am posting now as well as the comment which I posted 16 minutes ago

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The retrieval of this symbol history poses a considerable challenge, as it is scarcely mentioned in textbooks, Google Books and Google Scholar. The current application of the triangle symbol, distinct from the capital Greek letter delta, can be traced back to the mid-1700s in pre-modern chemistry. This is evidenced in Torbern Bergman's 1735-1784 work, "A Dissertation on Elective Attractions," accessible via the Internet Archive. At the end of the book, originally written in Latin, there is long list of symbols with explanations as shown below. In this context, the inverted triangle represented water, while the upright triangle symbolized the "matter of heat," aligning with symbolic alchemy. Wikipedia has a nice page on [Alchemical Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemical_symbol). For these reasons, it will be impossible to assign a single person behind this notation.

[image]

Comment: Here are the tables: http://www.chymist.com/Torbern%20Bergman.pdf

Comment: And here the entire translated thesis: https://archive.org/details/adissertationon00berggoog/page/n93/mode/1up

Comment: Apparently, arrows weren't used until about 100 years later: https://www.chemistryviews.org/details/ezine/2746271/History_and_Usage_of_Arrows_in_Chemistry/

Comment: The reference establishes the triangle as a reaction condition (at high temperature, typically in a crucible), distinct from reactions in aqueous solution (designated by a triangle with tip pointing downward).

Comment: @Karsten, The history of arrows is also interesting. Thanks for the links

Comment: @AChem Thank you for your answer. It's quite intriguing. I'm also intereted in the temporal gap between the usages in alchemy and modern chemistry.

Answer (score 7):

It can be mentioned that the triangle was used as the Alchemical symbol for fire in ancient times. However I don't know if it has been in continuous use as a reaction-symbol that way since, or if it fell out of use and the modern symbol is taken from Delta and is similar only by random coincidence.

Comment: This explanation makes much more sense than the link to $\Delta H$, which could mean exothermic or endothermic, and is only loosely connected to heat transfer. I would be nice to find a reference, though.

Comment: Another related link, I'll let somebody else judge on its reputability https://www.eoht.info/page/%CE%94

Comment: @Karsten: Alchemist's symbol for [fire](https://www.thoughtco.com/alchemy-symbols-and-meanings-4065063).

Comment: @user55119 I have found reputable sources documenting the alchemists symbol for fire. The question is whether this is a coincidence or the symbol with the arrow is meant to symbolize fire.

Comment: @Karsten - I wonder if it would be more likely to get a documented answer at History of Science SE? I tried to flag it to be migrated there, but it's too old to migrate. Maybe as a moderator you can override that (if you agree)?

Comment: @Andrew I guess I could post a new question there, more focused on when the triangle symbol first appeared in a chemical equation, and referencing this question. Ian Bush mentioned a wacky reference "eoht.info" that makes some specific claims, but I don't have access to the historic sources to check.

Comment: @Karsten Another symbol for heating I saw over reaction arrows is a circle with a  diagonal line crossing it

Comment: @Karsten Thank you very much for finding the interesting history of the use of Delta in alchemy. I didn't expect my question would see any progress. I'm glad that you post a more specific question about the history of the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Gosh folks! Way back when the only convenient laboratory heat source was a candle or Bunsen burner the symbol for heating was an isosceles triangle placed below the reaction arrow. It symbolized the shape of a candle or BB flame. With the advent of typewriters and computer fonts a symbol was needed; the equilateral triangle was the best available so the isosceles morphed into an equilateral. That it happens to be a Greek delta and is chemspeak for change is a coincidence.  My only source is that I am old enough to have lived thru all this nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes. Unfortunately all the high school teachers and college professors who told us this are all dead.

Answer (score -3):

Δ symbolizes difference. For chemical reactions, it's usually difference between energy that reactants already have and energy needed for reaction. Then Δ = $E_a$ - activation energy of the reaction. Activation energy is like a "potential barrier" for reaction to happen. And Δ means that we've *added* this amount of energy so energy of reactants *changed* by Δ (difference).